# How do I print an indicator (triangle shape) on a SPECIFIC date in pine script

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I am trying to print a triangle shape on 3 specific dates in pine script.  I cannot get the shapes to print on any of the below dates.

```
    //@version=4`
    study(title = "Mercury Pivot", shorttitle="Mercury Pivot", overlay =true)`

    //These are the dates which i want the Triangle to be printed below 
    t1 = timestamp(2017, 11, 1, 0, 0) // 1st of November 2017
    t2 = timestamp(2018, 11, 1, 0, 0) // 1st of November 2018
    t3 = timestamp(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0) // 1st of November 2019

    //If the time is equal to the above date, print/display a triangle below the date with the text 
    "pivot"
    if time = t1
    plotshape(style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, text="PIVOT")

    if time = t2 
    plotshape(style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, text="PIVOT")

    if time = t3 
    plotshape(style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, text="PIVOT")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the date built-ins is more reliable. See alternate method in this code, and chart where only those markers show.
2. You can't plot from inside an `if` block. Need to include condition
   in your `plotshape()` call.

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Mercury Pivot", shorttitle="Mercury Pivot", overlay =true)

//These are the dates which i want the Triangle to be printed below 
t1 = timestamp(2017, 11, 1, 0, 0) // 1st of November 2017
t2 = timestamp(2018, 11, 1, 0, 0) // 1st of November 2018
t3 = timestamp(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0) // 1st of November 2019
plotshape(time == t1 or time == t2 or time == t3, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, text="PIVOT", size=size.normal, transp=60)
// Alternate method.
tt1 = year == 2017 and month == 11 and dayofmonth == 1
tt2 = year == 2018 and month == 11 and dayofmonth == 1
tt3 = year == 2019 and month == 11 and dayofmonth == 1
plotshape(tt1 or tt2 or tt3, "tt", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color.fuchsia, text="PP", size=size.small, transp=0)
```

[image]